# Changing the font for selected segment in uisegmentedcontrol

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm noticing that on one of my segmentedcontrols, it is hard to see which segment is selected.  I was thinking I could bold the font, or increase the font size just slightly.  I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    NSDictionary *fontDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:boldFont, UITextAttributeFont, nil];
    [_tableSegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:fontDict forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

My text looks the same in both segments of the segment control.  Do I need to do something like this instead?
[Change textColor in UISegmentedcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032091/change-textcolor-in-uisegmentedcontrol)

I was hoping for the easier approach in iOS 5 with the appearance additions if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280391/change-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure but i think [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
f was missing. try this and tell me

also NSlog the value of dictionary to check whether the value is set propery or not

else use

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
this i have seen some times prblems are due to this. i dont know why this is.